# historical price data for Sdax Index

Tags: finance, germany

I am looking for historical price data in .csv or .txt format to download for the following financial instrument:

Sdax Performance Index (It's a german smallcap indice in case you care)

```
ISIN: DE0009653386
RIC: ^SDAXI
```

I need the data starting from 30.12.1987 as far as possible.

Comment: you could always offer a bounty on here...